# Converting raster to vector and creating polygons based on each pixel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, convert, polygon-creation, polygonize

I want to convert a raster file (100x100m pixel size) which contains population counts as pixel values. I need a vector-based file of the 100x100m grids and the population as attributes.

I tried different conversion methods in QGIS, but there will always be pixels merged together.

Is there a way to create a vector grid and assign the raster values to them?

Comment: Adjacent pixels with the same values are merged together when converted to polygons? You could create a fishnet and intersect with output to recreate the grid

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to create the fishnet to match it with the same position as the raster cells?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

Yet another option would be SAGA **Raster values to points** tool (`QGIS Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector <-> raster`).
Choose `[1] cells` as *Type* option.

**SAGA - Raster values to points**

[image]

note white moth-eaten appearance, which is nodata holes.

---

It was not clear what particular tools you have already tried, but one of them might have been GRASS `r.to.vect` tool (*Type: area*), which yields something like you have described: **GRASS - r.to.vect**

[image]

note internal nodata cells are treated as independent parts by GRASS

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can do it directly with [OpenJUMP Plus](http://www.openjump.org/).
Open your raster as a Sextante raster layer and use this tool

[image]

As a result you'll get a polygon layer that contains the pixel values as attributes. The other option "Create Lattice" creates points instead of polygons. In the image below blue rectangles are the generated polygons and attribute info is shown from the two selected and highlighted polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Since QGIS 3.4](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog34/index.html#feature-new-raster-pixels-to-polygons-algorithm) there is an algorithm called ["Raster pixels to polygons"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#raster-pixels-to-polygons).

You can find it in the `Processing Toolbox -> Vector creation -> Raster pixels to polygons`

[image]

For more details check [the pull requests](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/7239) on GitHub.